# Implementing autoplay with useEffect and setTimeout

Tags: reactjs

```
  const [activeIndex, setActiveIndex] = useState(0)
  const timeoutRef = useRef()

  useEffect(() => {
    timeoutRef.current && clearTimeout(timeoutRef.current)

    const timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
     setActiveIndex((prev) =>
        activeIndex >= items.length - 1 ? 0 : prev + 1
      )
    }, 3000)
    console.log({ timeoutId })//logs a different ID with every re-render
    timeoutRef.current = timeoutId

    return () => clearTimeout(timeoutId);
  }, [activeIndex, items.length]);
```

I'm trying to implement a slider which takes an array of items (images), then 'slides' through them automatically. I have this code for the autoplay functionality, and it works, but it seems like there are unnecessary re-renders. Is it a problem that the timeoutId changes with every render? I'm not getting errors in my console, but I know setting state in a useEffect is usually not a good idea.

Comment: Do you need the ability to manually advance, or will it only ever advance automaticly?

Comment: It'll probably have both options